# How to call Angular2 method from JavaScript or how to integrate YouTube Iframe API

Tags: javascript, youtube, typescript, angular

I am trying to integrate YouTube iframe API with Angular2 application.

YouTube API calls "onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()" method after it is ready.

I am having troubles in integrating it with my Angular2 app. Ideally I would bootstrap app in that method or call my app method but I can not figure out how to do it.

Since I am using TypeScript I can not call ng.bootstrap method.

Any hints?